# Google Analytics Social Interactions via. gtag.js

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js, analytics.js

Google Analytics documentation seems light on this topic, but historically businesses have been able to track social sharing interactions on their websites - 'Social Plugins' - via. both ga.js and analytics.js. See here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1316556?hl=en

For use case example, as a business, an analyst would like to understand how often website content is shared onto social networks by website visitors.

The problem I'm having is, I can't easily find what the gtag.js equivalent is of this functionality. The closest I can find is to send a gtag event called 'share' - but not sure if this will populate the Social Report under Acquisition in Google Analytics.

Could anyone please advise how to track Social Interactions via. gtag.js for Google Analytics?

```
//ga.js
_gaq.push(['_trackSocial', network, socialAction, opt_target, opt_pagePath]);
> https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSocial

//analytics.js
ga('send', 'social', [socialNetwork], [socialAction], [socialTarget], [fieldsObject]);
> https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/social-interactions
```

Note: I found this website which website - https://www.balkanweb.com/peshq-te-barabarte-pavaresisht-nga-madhesia/ - which does seem to use gtag event 'share' function but I am just not sure if it populates the Social reports in GA as I can't see any documentation to support that.

```
gtag('event','share',{method:'twitter',event_action:'tweet',content_id:targetUrl})
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a test and I confirm that the `share` event mentioned does not end up in the social report but in the event report.

Since the *gtag.js* documentation does not mention social hits (the parameter can only be: CONFIG, SET or EVENT) I believe there is currently no way to send that type of interactions from the website with gtag.

Comment: Thanks @Michele Pisani, that's a very helpful test. I will try and contact Google support to get their advice on this - will report back if I hear anything.

Comment: This article - https://newsinitiative.withgoogle.com/training/states/ntg/assets/ntg-playbook.pdf - is sitting on a Google domain and suggests using this approach below - page 74. But presuming it also just flows into event report.. 

`gtag('event', 'social share', {
 'event_category': 'NTG social',
 'event_label': 'facebook',
 'non_interaction' : false
});`

Comment: I tested it and hitType is 'event' in this case too.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no way to translate this social hit type from UA (Universal Analytics) to GA4 (Google Analytics 4) directly.

The Universal Analytics to Google Analytics 4 migration guide (by Google) mentions this in the [Hit types section](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9964640?hl=en#hit-types&zippy=,in-this-article) of the document comparing the two:

> Universal Analytics hit types include page hits, event hits, ecommerce hits, and social interaction hits.
>
> In contrast, Google Analytics 4 data is event-based, with the principle that any interaction can be captured as an event. As such, **Universal Analytics property hit types translate to events in a Google Analytics 4 property**.

Further down the document it also says:

> [...] it’s better to rethink your data collection in terms of the Google Analytics 4 model rather than port your existing event structure to Google Analytics 4.